# Wordpress 403 Forbidden "You don't have permission to access / on this server."

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

I can't access any pages/login to my WordPress based website.
I get this message:
*Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server.*
after some research on StackOverflow and other WordPress support forums I tried to change the .htacess file without success, also tried to duplicate it from the root directory to /wp-admin again nothing has changed...  But I'm not really sure about what I did...

I went back to how it was when it stopped working
permissions are 705 for the folder and 604 for the .htaccess file which is :

```
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_3
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I'm using WP 3.4 and I don't know if I use PHP 5.3 (what says the .htaccess 1st line) or 4.0.1 (on PHPMyAdmin from the website host access 'OVH')

Thank you very much for your attention.
Ismaël

Comment: Try to add `Options +FollowSymLinks` at the beginning of the htaccess

Comment: Thx, Tried this already before and instead of the 1st line : not working in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Make WP recreate the `.htaccess` the file itself.

Delete `.htaccess` via FTP, then change your permalink structure to default, then back to your desired permalink style. This will recreate the `.htaccess`. if that fails, you can try to reinstall the WP core by deleting everything except `wp-content` and `wp-config.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WP All-in-One Security plugin, be sure to check the `.htaccess` file in the root of your Wordpress installation, and look for a section on whitelisted IP addresses. If your current IP is not in the list, then you will get the 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Found this when looking for a similar issue I had.  Cause & fix was different but may be useful to others... 
I have some content external to the WordPress implementation, in a directory called "Documents" (outside the WordPress hierarchy). I then wanted a Wordpress page to list those documents so I called the page "Documents".  Accessing that page gave an error.  The fix was to rename the directory as "docs" (moving it to wp-content may have worked too).